# popcorn.js googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, popcornjs

Is there a secret to getting the googlemaps plugin to work with popcorn.js. I can get footnotes, normal video, youtube etc. to work but not the googlemaps stuff. Is there some other configuration or extra scripts required? I have looked at the videos on the popcorn.js site and cannot even get their googlemaps example to work.  I cannot find any reference in their api documentation to any additonal scripts required.

Comment: One should also note that the the .googlemaps() embedding doesn't work on a local site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather easy - I needed to set a width and height for the div I was using to display the map.